# using python to determine dot1x protocol type in ethernet header

Tags: python, protocols, ethernet, packet-capture

I'm using python to enumerate information in a `dot1x` exchange but I'm having trouble parsing the Ethernet protocol. I know the Ethernet type field is two bytes and `dot1x` uses "888e". I've confirmed "888e" is being passed via Wireshark but I'm getting the below output. Why is it showing "36488" instead of "888e"?

```
Destination MAC : 01:80:c2:00:00:03 Source MAC : c2:04:17:9c:f1:03 Protocol : 36488
Destination MAC : 01:80:c2:00:00:03 Source MAC : 08:00:27:83:5b:8b Protocol : 36488
Destination MAC : 01:80:c2:00:00:03 Source MAC : c2:04:17:9c:f1:03 Protocol : 36488
Destination MAC : 01:80:c2:00:00:03 Source MAC : 08:00:27:83:5b:8b Protocol : 36488
Destination MAC : 01:80:c2:00:00:03 Source MAC : c2:04:17:9c:f1:03 Protocol : 36488
```

My code:

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *

#Convert a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into a dash separated hex string
def eth_addr (a) :
    b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
    return b

#create a AF_PACKET type raw socket (thats basically packet level)
#define ETH_P_ALL    0x0003          /* Every packet (be careful!!!) */
try:
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + '   Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# receive a packet
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #parse ethernet header
    eth_length = 14

    eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
    print 'Destination MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[0:6]) + ' Source MAC : ' +  eth_addr(packet[6:12]) + ' Protocol : ' + str(eth_protocol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of hexadecimal and decimal representation.

`36488` is `8e88` in hexadecimal. Also you are doing a `ntohs()` translation to get the `eth_protocol` which basically changes the byte order i.e. translates `888e` to `8e88`.

If you want your program to print hexadecimal number check string formatting [specs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) at Python docs.

Comment: Can't belive I missed that. Thank you. I ended up substituting the line   "eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])" with "eth_protocol = hex(eth[2])".

Comment: @doby Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: I am using same line in my program: s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003)) and getting error that .. _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted .. what should I use instead of these parameters?